# Extract element from a dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, screen-scraping

Good evening from Austria!

I have tried to access an element from a dropdown list, but without any  success. The element where  the dropdown list is stored is:
. Once the button to the dropdown has been clicked, aria_controls = "mui-76755" appears with the corresponding element "mui-76755-option-0" (depending on the rank in the dropdown). I unfortunately havent figured out how to select the first element using Selenium in Python. For further info: https://directory.brcgs.com/ --> click on country --> select country.

Please help me solve this!

Code so far:

I attached my code below to show you what I have done so far.

```
url = 'https://directory.brcgs.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#root > div.page-container > div > div.PublicDirectory_publicDirectory__3yPKO > div.PublicDirectory_main__109y3 > div.FilterGroup_FilterGroup__1tA0A.PublicDirectory_filters__Rg1EU > div:nth-child(2)").click()
time.sleep(15)

input_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#root > div.page-container > div > div.PublicDirectory_publicDirectory__3yPKO > div.PublicDirectory_main__109y3 > div.FilterGroup_FilterGroup__1tA0A.PublicDirectory_filters__Rg1EU > div.MuiPaper-root.MuiAccordion-root.filter-row.Mui-expanded.MuiAccordion-rounded.MuiPaper-elevation1.MuiPaper-rounded > div.MuiCollapse-container.MuiCollapse-entered > div > div > div > div > div > div > div")
input_element.click()
time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Try using the below solution for your issue. I checked it out and it seemed to work :

    #click on the Country section to expand    
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiAccordionSummary-root"]').click()
    #Click on the dropdown to select a country
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment"]').click()
    #select the name of the country based on the country name Lets say *Chile*
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="MuiAutocomplete-listbox"]/*[text()[contains(.,"Chile")]]').click()

Comment: answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8132191/susovan-dey?fbclid=IwAR09xIWl5LxXNuOYBo2Gum-x3FKk9xRCr9IY-KHa9oHJvTXcF1iUQROEmWU